# Create array data each ID between two API Angular 9

Tags: arrays, angular, api, loops, arraylist

I am learn and stuck about this logic.
Do we could get array data from each ID between two API

Lets call first API get list ID

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then second API get list with detail data.
If this second API if no id at url (ex: htp://pokeapi.com/data/2) the result is null

```
{"by":"abc","id":2,"score":2000,"desc":"passed"}
```

I want get data from second API by id first API and
get the result array with all data

I have try it but not good lol.

```
.subscribe(
    (items) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var result = items[i];

        this.secondAPI
          .get({ id: result })
          .subscribe(
            (item) => {
              this.items = item;
              console.log('itemm ' + JSON.stringify(this.items));
            }
          );
      }
    },
    error => console.log('Error data ' + error)
  );
```

I have try others method with pass the data into Input
but not show the result (empty)

In player.ts

```
@Input() dataId: any;
items: any;

getPlayer() {
  this.firstAPI
    .get()
    .subscribe(
      items => {
        this.items = items;

        console.log('data ' + JSON.stringify(this.items));
      }
    );
}
```

and in Html file

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <ion-label routerLink="/detail/{{ item }}">
    <item class="player" [dataId]="item"></item>
  </ion-label>
</li>
```

Thank you for help!

**NOTE : I have done with this. Just passed data from other component.**

Answer (score 0):

use rxjs operator with pipe :

```
    .pipe(
         concatMap(x => x),
         switchMap(x => this.secondAPI.get({ id: x })),
         toArray()
    )
    .subscribe(item => console.log(item))
```

Comment: Hi bro. Yes like this but only single object show. How transform into array data each ID. Thanks

Comment: error TS2345: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
      Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<unknown>): Observable<unknown>'.

Comment: Ups i am forget to import toArray from rxjs.
But the only single object too. Then i am inspect the page.
I see in tab network the url api get repeat count total item
like this:
24122804.json 
24122685.json
24122465.json
24122340.json
24122325.json
next...